# How to convert a String to TimeSpan inside a Linq Expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm working with C# MVC EF Code First, where I have a Linq Expression as follows:

```
var data = new SchedulerAjaxData(new GTOpel().mxes.Select(e => new 
    { 
        id = e.nkeyid, 
        text = e.texto, 
        start_date = e.data, 
        end_date = e.data 
    })
);
```

My issue now is: I have got a DateTime field (data) which has the Date I want but it uses the default Time (00:00:00.000).
The format I have got on this field is something like "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
I have a Time field (hinicio) which is a String and not a DateTime/TimeSpan type - I want to add hinicio to data - let's give an example value to hinicio such as "13:00", since this is the format("HH:mm") the DB is using for the String.

In the end, this is what I'd like to get: "2016-01-01 13:00:00.000"

Since we're talking about a DateTime and a String, is there a reasonable way to format both values inside the IQueryable expression I mentioned above?
If not, how should I format my values before I use them on the Select method?
**UPDATE / MORE DETAILS:**
For those who might wonder about it, the variables id, text, start_date and end_date are mandatory for the Scheduler library, so I can see the events I've already got.
This Scheduler is a template which I'm using and now I'm trying to implement it with my DB.
More info at: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/

Thanks in advance & best regards,
Granvic

Comment: My advice is, do not store time as string in database. That is what DateTime/DateTimeoffset type is for.

Comment: How does your `hinicio` `string` look like? You could try to create new `DateTime` and combine it with the `Date` that you have.

Comment: Do you want the addition to be done by SQL Server, or can it happen clientside? There are also plenty of questions already discussing this very subject, have you tried searching?

Comment: what is the format of `hinicio`?

Comment: Format of data: Datetime .::. Format of hinicio: String

Comment: I can't modify the DB, I must adapt my Web App to what already exists.

Comment: yes, but I means `hinicio` values, these strings are like "12:15" or "12m", or just a number?

Comment: Format means how do the values in these strings look like? 'yyyy-MM-dd' ? 'MM/dd/YYYY'?  DateTime is not a format, it's a type. DateTime has *no* format, it's a binary value that gets *formatted* to strings based on several formats. The *default* format is whatever the system's locale defines. If you try to parse `29/3/2015' on a US computer you'd get an error because it would expect `3/29/2015`

Comment: Once again corrected, so it can be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert `hinicio` value to `TimeSpan`, then add it to `data`.

To do this in *Linq to Entities* you have to use `DbFunctions` and `SqlFunctions` classes.

If `hinicio` looks like `hh:mm` your query should be like this:

```
var data = new SchedulerAjaxData(new GTOpel().mxes.Select(e => new 
{
    ...
    start_date = DbFunctions.AddMinutes(e.data, 
                     DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(TimeSpan.Zero, 
                                             DbFunctions.CreateTime(SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", e.hinicio),
                                                                    SqlFunctions.DatePart("mi", e.hinicio), 
                                                                    0.0))) 
}));
```

Comment: Assuming `new GTOpel().mxes` returns an `IQueryable<T>`, this will throw an exception that Entity Framework can't translate `TimeSpan.Parse()` to a store expression.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! This worked swimmingly and now I can set my events properly! Thank you so much @arturo-menchaca , you can't imagine how much of a help this is to me!!!

Answer (score 0):

IF the format of the time in hinicio is a standard format (for example, 14:23 or 2:23 PM), then the conversion is easy:

```
start_date = e.data + DateTime.Parse(hinicio).TimeOfDay,
```

Comment: This can't work in LINQ to EF because it can't be translated to SQL. The results would have to be materialized first (eg with ToLinq()), and a `Select` could be applied to them

Comment: `PM` is not standard, it's a *localized* format that won't work on non-English locales. One *can* use all of the .NET parsing tricks though, like passing a specific culture to `Parse` or using `ParseExact` to match any format